# How to automatically change laptop's scaling factor when external display is (dis)connected?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, scaling

When I connect to my external monitor, the scaling factor I prefer is 1x but when I'm working only on my monitor's display, I prefer 1.10x.

Is there a way in which I can automate the process of changing this scaling factor in gnome-tweaks such that it switches to 1.10x scaling factor whenever I connect my laptop to another monitor using HDMI?